# Problema print en ciclo for

Tags: java

Quiero que el programa me pida cuántos números deseo ingresar y posteriormente me muestre si cada numero que ingresé es primo o no primo, pero en cambio estoy obteniendo que ingreso un número y me dice de inmediato si es primo o no, luego el siguiente numero y me dice si es primo o no, y así, con los n números que decida ingresar.

**Mi código:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        int N, i, z;
        N=leer.nextInt();
        for(i=1;i<=N;i++){
            z=leer.nextInt();

            if(z%2!=0||z==2){
                System.out.println("primo");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("no primo");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Y esto es lo que estoy obteniendo (verticalmente)

> 3
>   2
>   primo
>   1
>   no primo
>   5
>   primo

Cuando quiero es

> 3
>   2
>   1
>   5
>   primo  no primo  primo

Comment: Si lo quieres hacer así tienes que cambiar varias cosas. Tendrías que crear un array e ir metiendo ahí los números que quieras con un bucle y cuando lo llenes, con otro bucle recorrer el array e ir viendo si son primos o no

Comment: Adicional a lo que dice @PabloSimonDiEstefano no basta con comprobar que el resto de dividirlo entre 2 sea distinto de 0 o el numero sea 2. Tienes que recorrer desde el menos 1 hasta 2 para ver si tiene divisores. Aqui tienes como saber si es primo http://lineadecodigo.com/java/numeros-primos-en-java/

Comment: Debería ir comprobando el resto desde 2 hasta n/2. Así es como sabrá si es primo sin hacer más iteraciones de la cuenta. Supongo que donde JDev ha puesto "Tienes que recorrer desde el menos 1 hasta 2 ..." habrá querido decir "Tienes que recorrer desde el NUMERO QUE INTRODUCES menos 1 hasta 2 ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes actualmente es que lees el número dentro del bucle `for{}` e inmediatamente calculas su resultado, es por esto que tu programa no funciona como esperas.

Te paso algunas modificaciones que te pueden resultar útiles y te las explico un poco:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static boolean isPrimo(int numero) {
        // Función para indicar si un número es primo o no, tu manera de detectarlo
        // anteriormente también era erronea. esto lo puedes modificar como mejor veas.
        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numero; i++) {
            if ((numero % i) == 0) {
                contador++;
            }
        }
        if (contador <= 2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Primero se pide el número total de elementos que queremos evaluar para saber
        // si son primos o no.

        System.out.println("Inserte el total de números a evaluar: ");
        int totalNum = leer.nextInt();

        // Una vez que tienes el total de números, pasas a pedir que te inserten cada
        // uno de los mismos, por ejemplo si el total son 3, el usuario tiene que
        // introducir 3 números para ser evaluados. Estos números necesitas guardarlos
        // en un array para quue luego los puedas evaluar todos de golpe y no uno a uno
        // como es el caso que te ocurre actualmente.
        System.out.println("Ahora debe introducir un total de " + totalNum + " numeros: ");
        int[] numerosInsertado = new int[totalNum]; // Donde almacenarémos los números a evaluar
        for (int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++) {
            numerosInsertado[i] = leer.nextInt(); // Se guardan en la posición correspondiente.
        }

        // Una vez que ya tenemos todos los números insertados, pasamos a evaluarlos y
        // mostrar el resultado correspondiente a cada uno.
        System.out.println("El resultado es el siguiente: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++) {
            if (isPrimo(numerosInsertado[i])) {
                System.out.print(numerosInsertado[i] + " = primo; ");
            } else {
                System.out.println(numerosInsertado[i] + " = no primo; ");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto da el resultado que buscas:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Crear scanner
    System.out.println("¿Cuantos numeros?"); // Preguntar cuantos numeros
    int numbersToInput = scanner.nextInt(); // Guardar la cantidad de numeros
    boolean[] results = new boolean[numbersToInput]; // Crear un array para guardar los resultados de que numeros son primos

    for (int i = 0; i < numbersToInput; i++)
    {
        int newNumber = scanner.nextInt(); // Guardamos el numero que el usuario envia para comprobar si es primo

        // Si el numero es primo, añadimos "true" al array
        if (esNumeroPrimo(newNumber))
            results[i] = true;
        // Si el numero no es primo, añadimos "false" al array
        else
            results[i] = false;
    }

    // Hacemos un loop en el array de boolean, escribimos "primo" si es "true", "no primo" si no lo es
    for (boolean b : results)
        if (b)
            System.out.print("primo ");
        else
            System.out.print("no primo ");
    scanner.close();
}
```

Y por abajo tendrias algo como:

```
private static boolean esNumeroPrimo(int numero)
{
    // Aqui comprobarias si es primo o no
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Aqui se explica como comprobar si un numero es primo

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/

Comment: Hola tkap1, revisa tu código porque no dice si el número es primo o no, tu código dice si es divisible por 2. Sería óptimo que editases y explicases lo que hace el código para que el OP entienda todo lo que hace tu código